# Where can I get a virtual machine online?

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-access, vps

I am looking for some VPS/ Virtual machine which should be available all the time and I must be able to access it from any computer having internet.

I know a few paid services but just wondering If I can get a VM for free.

Comment: http://koding.com, http://c9.io, ideone does have an editor on it as well as filehosting though not exactly a VPS,

Comment: Instead of using VPS, just host files on a domain or free server if you have to and use an online IDE to edit them. If you find some of the quality free ones they will allow ftp, which is provided in most site domains.

Comment: https://0cloud0.com/playground you can get rhel7/8 centos7, fedora 30, ubuntu 18 VM for Practice

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[koding.com](http://www.koding.com) has a free VM running Ubuntu. The specs are pretty good, 1 gig memory for example. They have a terminal online you can access through their website, or use SSH. The VM will go to sleep approximately 20 minutes after you log out. The reason is to discourage users from running live production code on the VM. The VM resides behind a proxy. Running web servers that only speak HTTP (port 80) should work just fine, but I think you'll get into a lot of trouble whenever you want to work directly with other ports. Many mind-like [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/kodingen/) offer similar setups. Good luck!

I had the same idea as you but given all restrictions everybody keep imposing everywhere I feel that I must go out and pay for a VPS.

Comment: but koding.com doesn't allow server to "always run" unless upgraded to paid version

Comment: koding.com not working without AWS account :(

Comment: koding no longer provides a hosting features/

Answer (score 4):

You can get free Virtual Machine and many more things online for 3 months provided by Microsoft Azure. I guess you need VPN for learning purpose. For that it would suffice.

Refer http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

Comment: It also needs credit card :(

Comment: I like this choice because of the trial no matter how powerful the virtual machine is.  With amazon, you only get a weak machine to use for free.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

one year free. I do use this for a while.

Comment: It requires a credit card to create a free account which I don't have :( Any alternative?

Comment: buy prepaid visa card. does not require credit on it.